# Partition problem - разбиение множества на подмножества с одинаковой суммой, вариант динамического программирования

Tags: java, c++, c, алгоритм, динамическое-программирование

Есть входящий массив из чисел, например: {3, 2, 1, 6}. Нужно найти одинаковую сумму его подмножеств, т.е. в данном случае 6 (3+2+1 = 6).

Подробное описание решения задачи - http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-18-partition-problem/ (все данные далее с этой ссылки). В процессе решения динамическим программированием мы заполняем логическую таблицу:

[image]

```
int sum = 0;
int i, j;

// Caculcate sun of all elements
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  sum += arr[i];

if (sum%2 != 0)  
   return false;

bool part[sum/2+1][n+1];

// initialize top row as true
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
  part[0][i] = true;

// initialize leftmost column, except part[0][0], as 0
for (i = 1; i <= sum/2; i++)
  part[i][0] = false;     

 // Fill the partition table in botton up manner 
 for (i = 1; i <= sum/2; i++)  
 {
   for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)  
   {
     part[i][j] = part[i][j-1];
     if (i >= arr[j-1])
       part[i][j] = part[i][j] || part[i - arr[j-1]][j-1];
   }        
 }    

/* // uncomment this part to print table 
 for (i = 0; i <= sum/2; i++)  
 {
   for (j = 0; j <= n; j++)  
      printf ("%4d", part[i][j]);
   printf("\n");
 } */

 return part[sum/2][n];
```

Не могу понять логику заполнения, а именно строку:

```
part[i][j] = part[i][j] || part[i - arr[j-1]][j-1];
```

Нужно объяснить языком для обезьян, почему мы берем ячейку part[i - arr[j-1]][j-1] с такими то индексами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Логика такова: разберем сначала строку

```
part[i][j] = part[i][j-1];
```

- если из предыдущего столбца (ну то есть подмножества на j-1 итерации) можно составить число равное i, то из массива, в котором на один элемент больше, то уж тем более можно. Ну допустим i=3, подмножество на предыдущей итерации: {2,1}, подмножество на текущей итерации: { 2,1,10 }. То понятно, что если из {2,1} можно составить 3, то из большего подмножества это также можно сделать.

Теперь строка:

```
part[i][j] = part[i][j] || part[i - arr[j-1]][j-1];
```

Забудем пока про оператор или, а глянем на правую часть выражения.

arr[j-1] - это элемент, который добавляется к предыдущему подмножеству, чтоб получить текущее подмножество. (минус один потому, что отчет цикла начинается с единицы, а нумерация массива идет с нуля).

[j-1] столбец - это столбец с предыдущим подмножеством.

А теперь в чем магия строки [i - arr[j-1]]. Ну покажу конкретный пример, думаю так понятней будет. Например в роли arr[j-1] у нас является число 3, i = 5. И вот надо проверить, можно ли из текущего подмножества составить число 5. Как это узнать? У нас есть наше текущее число 3, но 3 - это не 5. Чтоб получить 5 не хватает ещё 2. И мы смотрим, если из предыдущего подмножества можно составить 2, то и вместе с нашей текущей тройкой можем составить 5. Т.е. в этой строке от необходимой нам суммы вычитаем наш текущий элемент, и смотрим, можно ли составить это число из предыдущего подмножества.

Ну а теперь оператор или. Ну нам собственно не важно, как именно нам составить это число. Есть два способа проверить это (ну это или уже проверено на предыдущем подмножестве, либо мы будем пытаться составить это вместе с нашим новым числом) - и не важно как именно. Если хоть каким-то способом вышло, то ставим true.

Answer (score 3):

Принято считать, что динамическое программирование - это когда мы придумываем некую структуру данных, чаще всего массив требуемого размера с нужным количеством измерений (part в вашем коде), и хитрый алгоритм итеративного рекуррентного заполнения этой структуры. Когда в процессе заполнения мы доходим до определенных индексов - значение по этим индексам и будет являться ответом на вопрос задачи. Но нередко алгоритм заполнения неочевиден и непрозрачен, поэтому возникают подобные вопросы.

Предлагаю следующий подход: рекурсия + мемоизация. В некоторых источниках это также называется термином динамическое программирование, с чем я абсолютно согласен. Для поставленной задачи (и для большинства подобных) очень просто придумать тривиальный рекурсивный алгоритм, для этой задачи его реализация выглядит так:

```
bool f(int i, int s) {
    return (s==0) ? true : (i<0) ? false : f(i-1, s) || f(i-1, s-a[i]);
}
```

Функция (по вашей ссылке приведена аналогичная) вызывается с максимальным индексом массива и половиной суммы его элементов, возвращает истину, если мы можем набрать множество элементов массива на половину его суммы. Задача решена, но при больших размерах массива рост времени работы будет экспоненциальный (как в тех же Фибоначчах). Решение - завести массив, куда записывать единожды рассчитанные значения функции. Функция у нас двухаргументная, массив удобно сделать двумерным. И при очередном вызове нашей функции f проверять - если значение с такими аргументами уже было рассчитано (есть значение в нашем массиве), то брать его, а не проваливаться дальше в экспоненциально-рекурсивные вызовы. Наша функция чистая, без побочных эффектов, поэтому такой подход корректен. И внезапно обнаруживается, что массив part в приведенном коде играет ровно ту же самую роль! И заполняется в итоге теми же самыми значениями! И не надо придумывать хитрый алгоритм его итеративно-рекуррентного заполнения, волшебная рекурсия все сделает за нас :) Хотя при желании этот алгоритм несложно вывести из известной логики имеющейся рекурсивной функции.

Comment: TL;DR; это не одно и тоже!. Полностью не согласен с такой интерпретацией. Рекурсия с мемоизацией (почему нету р не знаю, так принято) и динамическое программирование - разные методы, у них частично пересекается область применения но это не значит что это одно и тоже. Метод ДП почти всегда эффективнее по скорости работы и памяти, он не требует стека. Однако этот метод нормально применим только в случае простой топологической ориентации графа (по которому идёт обход рекурсии).

Comment: В своем комментарии я акцентировал внимание на общих чертах этих методов, чтобы донести мысль до автора вопроса. Если же выявлять различия - да, рекурсивный вариант расходует стек (хотя это не так однозначно, например в языках типа Haskell нет мутабельности а стек частично располагается в куче, поэтому такие рекурсивно-мемоизированные алгоритмы не приводят к стековерфлоу). С другой стороны, есть задачи, где не требуется заполнять всю ДП-структуру - а мемоизация при рекурсии заполнит только то, что надо.

Comment: Но повторюсь - я специально выделил общие черты алгоритмов, чтобы ТС в будущих подобных задачках сам смог реализовать классическое ДП из наивного рекурсивного алгоритма.